# Interacting with nested iframes in py selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-requests

I'm trying to automate a signup page that is made using google scripts and has nested iframes that I am unable to get around, my current solution is as follows

```
 def signin(args): # args: {"guess": "password", "url": url, "cookie": cookieDict], "usr": "username"}
    
    import re

    guess = args["guess"]
    url = args["url"]
    cookie = args["cookie"]
    usr = args["usr"]
    usr = usr
    
    jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
    if cookie is None:
        import pickle
        cookie = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))

    for c in cookie:
        jar.set(c["name"], c["value"], domain=c["domain"], path=c["path"])

    pars = params
    pars["pass"] = "#"+guess
    pars["uname"] = usr
    r = requests.Session()
    r.cookies = jar

    r = r.post(url, headers=header, params=pars)

    if "App is closed for students" not in str(r.content):
        # decode the maual way
        studentInfo = str(r.content).replace(r'\\x3c', '<').replace(r'\\x3e', '>').replace(r'\\x3d', '=').replace(r'\\x22', '"').replace(r'\\x7b', '{').replace(r'\\x7d', '}').replace(r'\\x2f', '/').replace(r'\\x3a', ':').replace(r'\\x2c', ',').replace(r'\\x5c', '\\').replace(r'\\x27', "'").replace(r'\\x3b', ';').replace(r'\\x5b', '[').replace(r'\\x5d', ']').replace(r'\\\\"','"').replace(r'\\\\/', '/').replace(r'\\\\n', '\n').replace(r'\\/','/').replace(r'\\n', '\n').replace(r'\\"', '"').replace(r'\\/', '/').replace(r'\\', '').replace(r'\\26','&')
        try:
            studentInfo = re.search("<hidden id=\"studentId\" data-student='(.*)'>", studentInfo).group(1)
            # replace all encoded characters
            studentInfo = studentInfo.replace("&amp;", "&").replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">").replace("&quot;", '"').replace("&#39;", "'")
            studentInfo = json.loads(studentInfo)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return [False, guess, r.status_code, r.text]
    else:
        return [True, guess, r.status_code, "App Closed"]

    if ('required' in str(r.content)) and (r'Invalid username and\\/or password.' not in str(r.content)):
        return [True, guess, r.status_code, studentInfo]
    else:
        return [False, guess, r.status_code, r.text]
```

Cookies are from a google authentication and filter for google domains. Page inital html is just an iframe with an external source that creates another iframe that contains the ui.

I have looked through lots of forums and found nothing better than request sessions, but this lacks the ability to interact with the website as it uses 'one time google generated tokens' which is preferable.

Is there a better way than request sessions or a way to do it in selenium?

I have tried using selenium to locate elements but it always returns 'no such element', this happens with all methods of locating elements.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"sandboxFrame")))
```

-return an error

```
[14232:10856:1206/110139.141:ERROR:util.cc(133)] Can't create base directory: C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleUpdater
Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        (No symbol) [0x0070F243]
        (No symbol) [0x00697FD1]
        (No symbol) [0x0058D04D]
        (No symbol) [0x005BC0B0]
        (No symbol) [0x005BC22B]
        (No symbol) [0x005EE612]
        (No symbol) [0x005D85D4]
        (No symbol) [0x005EC9EB]
        (No symbol) [0x005D8386]
        (No symbol) [0x005B163C]
        (No symbol) [0x005B269D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x009A9A22+2655074]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0099CA24+2601828]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x007B8C0A+619850]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x007B7830+614768]
        (No symbol) [0x006A05FC]
        (No symbol) [0x006A5968]
        (No symbol) [0x006A5A55]
        (No symbol) [0x006B051B]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76217BA9+25]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7722BB3B+107]
        RtlClearBits [0x7722BABF+191]
```

iframe information:

```
    id='sandboxFram'
    Title='title here'
    xpath='/html/body/iframe
```

Page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="chromevox" content-script="no">
<title>App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" nonce="code"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/macros/client/css/2498103415-mae_html_css_ltr.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/macros/client/js/2838233174-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js" nonce="nonce"></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="sandboxFrame" title="App" allow="allows" sandbox="permissions">
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="Na-nbmgTUciE6SvnTZ0S4w">
(function() {
var el = document.getElementById('sandboxFrame');
el.onload = function() {
goog.script.init("[page source]");
el.src = 'https:\/\/n-[more-stuffs]-2lu-script.googleusercontent.com\/userCodeAppPanel';
}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the URL, otherwise it will be difficult to debug.

Comment: The page is restricted to google accounts of a specific domain.

Comment: Can you post at least that specific page's full HTML source?

Comment: Sure, I add the base source, which loads the iframe with html ([page source]) within the function.